# android: java.lang.Object[] cannot be cast to android.widget.Button[]

Tags: android, arrays, object, button

### Declarations:

```
   // collections of spots (Buttons) and Animators 
   private final Queue<Button> spots = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Button>();
```

### adding new spot:

```
   public void addNewSpot()
   {
       int x = random.nextInt(viewWidth - SPOT_DIAMETER);
       int y = 0 - SPOT_DIAMETER;                      

       int x2 = x;
       int y2 = (viewHeight);

      // create new spot
      final Button spot = (Button) layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.untouched, null);
      spot.setPadding(0,0,0,0);
      spots.add(spot);
```

### checking all inflated spots

```
  public void Check_all_Spot(int BOY_X)
   {  
       int [] lowest_x;
       int [] lowest_y;
       int apple_shown_length =0;
       Button [] apple_shown; 

       String text_x ="";
       String text_y = "";

       if (!spots.isEmpty())
       {
           apple_shown = (Button[]) spots.toArray(); //LINE 684
           apple_shown_length = apple_shown.length;
       }

       lowest_x =  new int [apple_shown_length];
       lowest_y =  new int [apple_shown_length];
       apple_shown =  new Button [apple_shown_length];

       for (int w = 0; w < apple_shown_length ; ++w)
       {
           lowest_x[w] = (int) apple_shown[w].getX();
           lowest_y[w] = (int) apple_shown[w].getY();              
           text_x = text_x+ lowest_x[w];
           text_y = text_y+ lowest_y[w];            
       }

       image_boy.setText("lowest spot\n"+text_x+"\n"+text_y);
   }
```

## Logcat:

```
12-01 00:57:12.760: E/AndroidRuntime(14706): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-01 00:57:12.760: E/AndroidRuntime(14706): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Object[] cannot be cast to android.widget.Button[]
12-01 00:57:12.760: E/AndroidRuntime(14706):    at com.abc.abc.Game_collecting_view.Check_all_Spot(Game_collecting_view.java:684)
12-01 00:57:12.760: E/AndroidRuntime(14706):    at com.abc.abc.Game_collecting_view.Increment(Game_collecting_view.java:777)
12-01 00:57:12.760: E/AndroidRuntime(14706):    at com.abc.abc.Game_collecting_view$RptUpdater.run(Game_collecting_view.java:754)
12-01 00:57:12.760: E/AndroidRuntime(14706):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
12-01 00:57:12.760: E/AndroidRuntime(14706):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-01 00:57:12.760: E/AndroidRuntime(14706):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-01 00:57:12.760: E/AndroidRuntime(14706):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
12-01 00:57:12.760: E/AndroidRuntime(14706):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-01 00:57:12.760: E/AndroidRuntime(14706):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-01 00:57:12.760: E/AndroidRuntime(14706):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1008)
12-01 00:57:12.760: E/AndroidRuntime(14706):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:775)
12-01 00:57:12.760: E/AndroidRuntime(14706):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

### Question:

I would like to obtain the x and y coordinates of all the spots in the screen.

Yet the logcat reports `java.lang.Object[] cannot be cast to android.widget.Button[]`. How could the error be corrected? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have researched some more and it seems to be working in this way:

```
   public void Check_all_Spot(int BOY_X)
   {  
       int [] lowest_x;
       int [] lowest_y;
       int apple_shown_length =spots.size();
       Button [] apple_shown = null; 

       String text_x ="";
       String text_y = "";

       if (!spots.isEmpty())
       {
           apple_shown = spots.toArray(new Button[apple_shown_length]);
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
           apple_shown = (Button[]) spots.toArray(); //LINE 684
```

apple_show -> Type Button

spots -> Type Queue

You are trying to cast spots in a Button. It's not possible